# Правильно ли выражение? (поэтическое, упрощено)

Tags: психолингвистика

"Боль минутной раны годами заглушить не мог". По моему, проблема в выражении со словом "годами"
Не вернее  ,например?- "Боль минутной раны с годами заглушить не смог".

Спасибо большое за столь быстрый, живой ответ. Жаль , Вы меня не поддержали.
Вот мои рассуждения (я не лингвист, но механик, но попробую…).
Боль проходит с годами, со временем. (выражение - время лечит)
Боль проходит годами -  смысл выражения не совсем понятен, как бы, не точен.
Если грубо воспринять: «Годами заглушить не мог» (заглушить боль можно таблетками, водкой, в конце концов, годами нельзя …).
«Годами» здесь звучит как, как продолжительное время без начала и конца. Пример: Зима (мороз) стоит годами. И если сказать:    Зима (мороз) стоит с годами – очень плохо.
Другой пример «С годами стал умней» - очень хорошо (здесь есть событие-начало, т.е. был дураком (извините) – стал умным)
 "Боль минутной раны годами заглушить не мог"
Здесь начало есть, есть событие (Минутная рана (да - полученная за минуту)). Почему же по-вашему «годами» здесь лучше?
 Можете (ударение на «можете»)  ответить в терминах, с названиями частей речи, правилами Русского языка? т.е аргументированно по научному. 
За контекстом дело не станет. (Перевод с белорусского стихотворения А.Кулешова «Алеся», (написано автором в 14 лет). Песня «Алеся» в исполнении легендарной группой «Песняры»)
 Автор перевода «Незнамо К», привожу полностью:

Прощай, разбуженная сердцем, дорогая.
И отчего же мне так горько, не пойму.
Наверно, зорьку жаль, что в небе догорает,
Чтобы с восходом дню заняться моему.

А помнишь первое несмелое признанье
И май, что жаворонком плакал в вышине?..
Потом рассвет и небо серое в тумане,
Твой взгляд суровый и отчаянье во мне.

Ушла ты, любая, под шепот желтых сосен,
Ушла, безмолвная, под ропот волн ржаных
Туда, где нежные баюкали колосья
Мою печаль на перекрестке встреч былых.

Ушла за тихие, далекие просторы
Звездой рассветною, что гаснет в синеве.
Души обманутой горячие укоры
Слезой холодною застыли на траве.

Ушла, оставив непроглядные туманы,
Полынный дух объятых сумраком дорог,
Чтоб боль и горечь я от той минутной раны
Годами в сердце заглушить своем не мог.

Ушла и больше не воротишься, Алеся,
Прощай, смуглявая, любимая, прощай.
Стою на месте прежних встреч, а с поднебесья
Звенит и плачет, словно жаворонок, май.

Прощай, разбуженная в сердце, дорогая,
В душе я буду светлый образ твой нести.
Пусть эта зорька на востоке догорает,
Чтоб поздно вечером на западе взойти.

Comment: Я тем более не лингвист ))) Так что не стесняйтесь.  )))

С  контекстом понятно. Смысла больше не стало. Впрочем песенные стих - это вообще вещь в себе. Так что тут можно и не заморачиваться.

Comment: Не вижу никакой проблемы. Если сказать прозой, получится "Годами я не могу заглушить боль, полученную за минуту". То есть заглушаю, заглушаю, стараюсь - и не могу.
При чем тут "с годами"?

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что вернее "с годами". С годами - с возрастом, а речь не о возрасте, а о длительности страданий,нанесена рана за минуту, а болит года, так что автор свою мысль выразил точно, а уж что читатель напридумывает - это его дело. У каждого произведения есть автор и есть читатель-в какой-то мере соавтор, но поправлять автора, по-моему, не совсем корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Всем правильно. Можно и *с годами*, но здесь лучше именно *годами*.
*Годами* - это период. Днями, неделями месяцами... Веками, в конце концов.
Впрочем, судить о стилистике стихотворной строчки без контекста довольно сложно.

Не очень понятно, например, почему "боль раны" названа минутной. 
Или это рана минутная? Тогда тем более непонятно.

Comment: Наверное, получио рану за минуту, а болит - годами.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с предыдущими отвечающими. "Годами заглушить не смог" — здесь уместно даже в значении "чем". Например, "всей своей жизнью не смог заглушить". По крайней мере, ухо не режет.